# Possible to output Vowpal Wabbit predictions to .txt along with observed target values?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

We're writing a forecasting application that uses Vowpal Wabbit and are looking to automate as much of our model validation process as we can. Anyone know whether `vw` has a native utility to output the target values in a test file along with the predictions from a `vw` model? These values are printed to the terminal output during prediction. Is there an argument to the regular `vw` call, or perhaps a tool in the `utl` folder that prints targets and forecasts together on a row-wise basis?

Here's what the code I'm using now for prediction looks like:

```
vw -d /path/to/data/test.vw -t -i lg.vw --link=logistic -p predictions.txt
```

My goal is to produce from within Vowpal an output file that looks like this:

```
Predicted  Target
0.78       1
0.23       0 
0.49       1

...
```

**UPDATE**

@arielf's code worked like a charm. I've only made one minor addition to print the streaming results to a `validation.txt` file:

```
vw -d test.vw -t -i lg.vw --link=logistic -P 1 2>&1 | \
     perl -ane 'print "$F[5]\t$F[4]\n" if (/^\d/)' > validation.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
vw -d test.vw -t -i lg.vw --link=logistic -P 1 2>&1 | \
    perl -ane 'print "$F[5]\t$F[4]\n" if (/^\d/)'
```

Explanation:

```
-P 1     # Add option: set vw progress report to apply to every example
```

Note: `-P` is a capital `P` (alias for `--progress`), `1` is the progress printing interval.

Note that you don't need to add predictions with `-p ...` since that is redundant in this case (predictions are already included in `vw` progress lines)

A progress report line with headers, looks like this:

```
average   since     example    example   current  current   current
loss      last      counter     weight     label  predict  features
0.000494  0.000494        1        1.0   -0.0222   0.0000        14
```

Since progress report goes to stderr, we need to redirect stderr to stdout (`2>&1`).

Now we pipe the `vw` progress output into `perl` for simple post-processing. The `perl` command loops over each line of input without printing by default (`-n`), auto-splits into fields on white-space (`-a`), and applies the expression (`-e`) printing the 5th and 4th fields separated by a TAB and terminated by a newline if the line starts with a number (in order to skip whatever isn't a progress line, e.g. headers, preambles and summary lines).  I reversed the 5th & 4th filed order because `vw` progress lines have the observed value before the predicted value and you asked for the opposite order.

**UPDATE**

Aaron published a working example using this solution in Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzKSYsAMaJLjZzJlWFA2N3NnZGc

Comment: This is great stuff, and gets me exactly what I needed. Thank you for the clear explanation of the mechanics as well, in addition to the sample code.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron.  BTW: if you also want to have the header line in the output, you may prepend the following to the perl expression snippet: 'BEGIN { print "Predicted\tTarget\n"}' right at the beginning of the expression without the single-quotes. perl executes BEGIN clauses only once when it starts.

Comment: Awesome. Since you seem to be the man to ask about vw out here, do you know if nnet is setup to handle binary data? should it be coded [-1, 1] or [0, 1]? Working on a blog post with sample data and code that I'm planning to send out by end of day.

Comment: answered my own question here: https://ashokharnal.wordpress.com/2015/03/03/click-through-rate-prediction-using-neural-network-in-vowpal-wabbit-a-to-z/. looks like the answer is affirmative!

Comment: @Aaron Yes. `--nn` (single layer neural net model) is orthogonal to label value and to loss function.  You can pick any loss function you want and any label subset you want with `--nn`.  There's however a dependency between `--loss_ function=logistic` and label value.  When you use loss function logistic, vw assumes binary classification and a binary label value in {-1, 1}